# How to reset/clear HAS_MANY association relation with objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

For example,

```
staff = Staff.where(:id => 6).first
prize = Prize.where(:id => 3).first

staff.prizes.push(prize)
```

How to reset the relation  between the above staff and prize object ?

```
class Staff  
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :prizes


class Prize
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :staff
```

Comment: clear the relationship between them

Comment: try `staff.prizes.clear`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, the model with the `belongs_to` statement holds the [foreign key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association). That is, your `Prize` database table has a `staff_id` column. This column stores the id of a `Staff` model.

One way to clear this association is to set the prize's staff to `nil`:

```
prize.staff = nil
prize.save
```

You can also do this in one step with [ActiveRecord's `update` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update):

```
prize.update(staff: nil)
```

Alternatively, you could use [the `delete` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-delete-object) to remove a `prize`:

```
staff.prizes.delete(prize)
```